# Finding the xpath of a certain tag located in an Html Frameset

Tags: html, xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to find the xpath of a value in a table located in a frameset in a website to use it on a google spreadsheet for `=importxml()` to scrape data.
This is the website:
[https://eshop.wago.com](https://eshop.wago.com/JPBC/singleview/articleList.hbc?articleID=16452107&hasMand_16452107=false&noOfPages=1&pageNo=1&from=Catalog&priceTypeID=1&currency=%E2%82%AC&FS=Catalog)

```
<tr>
<td class="text">Connection technology (1)&nbsp;</td>
<td class="text">PUSH WIRE<sup>®</sup>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="text">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

For example I want to find the xpath of "Push wire®" right in front of the conncetion technology in the table on the mentioned webpage, when I use the following function in Google spreadsheet it doesn't give any value;

```
=IMPORTXML(A8, "//*/td[.,='Connection technology (1) ']/following::td[1]")
```

I think the reason is that the item is located in a frameset and when I try to address the frame with its class it still doesn't work! I am so confused right now. So how can I refer that in "importxml()"?

Comment: Your first problem is that this url is useless, and your program wont be work after 20 minutes, because, there is - for security issues -, an ID. You should first: try to get the HTML, then show it in your question, and then show your xpath. If not, it will be impossible to answer to you.

Comment: Well, this webpage is totally public and works fine if you open it twice! The first time you open it, for some weird reason which I really want to know, it redirects you to the homepage, but once you click on it for the second time it will show you the right page with the product and the tables!! I think it is the problem! I have no idea why the URL doesn't work at the first attempt! and due to that I believe the program can't scrape the data! I also found the direct url of the frame where the table is located in and it isn't working either, so we could not say that the issue is the frameset!

Comment: I updated the question, I put the html code and the url to the frameset that I want to scrape! thanks! it would be so great if you could answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer: you have several problems

**1 (out of scope): verify security issues.** It is rather usual that the server have not the same behaviour multiple times. It tracks you, authorizes, ...

**2 your xpath is not well-formed**

this works:

```
"//*/td['Connection technology (1) ']/following::td[1]"
```

or this, more robust:

```
"//*/td[contains(.,'Connection technology (1)')]/following::td[1]"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think as you mentioned the problem is the URL and the server because in spite of writing the right xpath I can't get any result in the Google spreadsheet through 'IMPORTXML' function. thanks anyways!